# How to set variable in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to set a variable for later use in SQL. My SQL query is as follows:

```
$sql ="SELECT *,$filterqueryage (
(
(
ACOS( SIN( (".$lat." * PI( ) /180 ) ) * SIN( (
 `latitude` * PI( ) /180 ) ) + COS( ( ".$lat." * PI( ) /180 ) ) * COS( (
 `latitude` * PI( ) /180 )
) * COS( (
( ".$lng." -  `longitude` ) * PI( ) /180 )
)
)
) *180 / PI( )
) *60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344
) AS distance
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN usermeta AS um1 ON u.id = um1.user_id
$filterquery

WHERE um1.meta_key = 'subjects'
AND um1.meta_value REGEXP '$subjectsvalues'
$filterqueryup 

GROUP BY u.ID
HAVING distance < $km $filterqueryupage ORDER BY distance ASC";
$users = DB::select($sql);
```

I would like to store the distance variable for use in the result display, the variable is used "AS distance" in the SQL query. How can i set the variable so i can call it in php, eg. $distance = $user->distance?

Comment: Just a note; when `LEFT JOIN`, move the right side table's conditions from `WHERE` to `ON` to get true left join behavior. (As it is now, you get regular `inner join` result.)

Comment: Hi Jarlh, im not really sure what you mean?

Comment: In your query, simply move `um1.meta_key = 'subjects'
AND um1.meta_value REGEXP '$subjectsvalues'` to the `ON` clause.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
'".$var."'
```

try to this way is work for me

Comment: How would you use this method as the distance variable is calculated in the SQL query?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10933582)

Comment: Could you please explain @jay?

Comment: if u add php variable value in sql query then add single cots before or after double cots of php variable like this  ( ' ".$lat." ' * PI( ) /180 ) )

Comment: Hi again, i want to use the variable set in the SQL query afterwards, i am using php variables in the query already, but i want to save the "distance" variable in the user object. Please read my post again, and ask questions if my question is unclear.

Comment: @SankarV can you help me?